# Parsing XPS or PDF and inserting data into a Word Template?

Tags: parsing, pdf, xps

So, I have an option of sending a document from a database to print either in PDF or XPS.  I need to be able to extract specific data, such as name, date, etc. from one of those formats and inserting that data into a word template.  The word template is not editable.  You can only type within fields... each field has a heading before it, such as name, dob, etc.

Basically I need to be able to automate transferring that information from the PDF or XPS file into the word template.

I'm familiar enough with C++, Python and Java.. so I have no language preference -- whatever gets the job done.

Could you suggest a way I can manage to accomplish this?  I've having a bit of a difficulty figuring out the way I can parse/extract data from one of those file types and which file type would be a better candidate.  And I definitely have no idea how I can automate the population of fields in the Word Template.

Oh and forgot to mention, this is on Windows 7 (and maybe 8, but mostly 7) machines.

Thank a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: Search this site for `[c++] parse pdf`, `[c++] word automation`, and try Google or Bing. This question is entirely too broad in scope. Questions here should be specific, and be limited to one answerable question per post. You've asked three (parsing PDF, parsing XPS, and populating a Word template), and they're all too vague to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for anyone who has the same sort of question, so this is how I did it:

I used PDFBox (http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to parse the document and extract the needed data and then I used docx4j (http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) to insert data into word template.  Both are incredible tools and have excellent communities that help out almost immediately.